# Автозаполнение логина и пароля в приложении под iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Каким образом можно реализовать сохранение пароля в цепочке ключей, чтобы при входе  в приложение на экране входа над клавиатурой показывалось подобным образом уведомление?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [здесь](https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/master/Keychain) простой пример. возможно это то, на что вы ищете ответ.

Comment: @dmtr смотрел, но, по-моему, это не то. Я так понимаю, сохранение паролей работает только для сайтов, но не понимаю, как заставить поля ввода вести себя как веб-элементы

Answer (score 2):

Короткая выжимка [из документации](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill):

- Вам нужно [привязать приложение к вашим сайтам](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/supporting_associated_domains_in_your_app), на которых люди вводят пароли обычно. При этом нужно использовать префикс `webcredentials`. На сами сайты нужно будет загрузить файл `.well-known/apple-app-site-association` со списком приложений.
- Для полей для логина и пароля нужно [задать соответствующий тип](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view) `UITextContentType`, будь это `.username` или `.password`. Или `.newPassword` в случае формы регистрации.

Например, так, в случае Swift:

```
userTextField.textContentType = .username
userTextField.keyboardType = .emailAddress
passwordTextField.textContentType = .password
```

В случае Xamarin iOS суть та же самая:

```
_txtField.TextContentType = UITextContentType.OneTimeCode;
```

[Справочник возможных значений в случае Xamarin.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uitextcontenttype?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)

Таким образом если человек имеет сохранённый в связке ключей пароль от вашего сайта, то его же система предложит ввести в самом приложении. Обратное тоже будет работать, то есть так, будто дело происходит на самом вашем сайте.

Конечно, ваш ждёт разочарование если вы хотите чтобы у вас в приложении работало автозаполнение для паролей, сохранённых для сайтов, к которым вы не имеете отношения, например, от vk.com: без разрешения владельцев какого-то сайта *невозможно* сделать автозаполнение данных входа, и это правильно. Представьте себе что кто-то сделал приложение, которое выдаёт себя за официальное для вашего сайта, на самом деле таким не являясь, вместо этого собирая пароли для каких-то не очень добрых целей. Само собой вы не захотите чтобы пароли можно было легко ввести в этом приложении.